# Cannot use import and require inside JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, importerror

I tried to use import in my JS file but it gave me a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module", otherwise if i use require it gives me "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at".

This is my folder structure. I use one import in the server.js file and work, in admin.js i have the problem that I write before.

[folder_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NPSV.png)

This is the import that I need to use.

```
 import admin from 'firebase-admin';

 var serviceAccount=require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

 admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "..."
 });
```

I have tried to write "type":"module" inside my package.json but this does not work, I also updated node but nothing the error still here. I think that maybe it return me that error for the organization of my folders but I don't know.

Comment: Are you actually running your JS with Node.js? Or are you running it in a web browser and have Node.js installed somewhere nearby? (I have seen people try that!)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I run JS with Node.js.

Comment: should be `"type":"module"`, and if you do so, you should use `import`, not require, so go check better your error, its stack trace, and fix the conflicting files lines

Comment: Why are you keeping admin.js next to admin.html and under the public folder in your folder structure if you are running it with node.js and not an HTML script element?

Comment: I have done a mistake writing the question in my .json I have "type":"module" and still don't work.

Comment: So how to I have to put my files in the structure?

Comment: My point is that you *claim* you are running the files with Node.js but the error message and the place you have put the files strongly implies that you are running them with a browser (and that Node.js’ involvement is just to act as a web server which sends admin.js to the browser without executing it)

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your file's extension from **.js** to **.mjs**

When you do that you don't need to have `"type":"module"` in your package.json